# Resources vs. Match in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When creating routes in my config/routes.rb file, there are really two ways to do it. One is to use a match statement such as:

```
match 'devices/:device_id/cards/destroy/:id' => 'Cards#destroy', :as => :delete_card_for_device
```

The other is to use the resources statement:

```
resources :products do
  member do
    get 'short'
    post 'toggle'
  end
end
```

At first I liked the match statement since I knew what it was doing and is simpler to understand, but the more I look at all of my match statements, the more I see that many of them could be replaced with a resources. Should I try to convert all of my match statements into resources? Are resources better than match statements?

Comment: resources will also provide the 7 canonical RESTful actions, so if you need those, resources is the way to go. If you don't need those I imagine it doesn't matter which way you go, but someone more knowledgeable can probably answer that part of the question

Answer (score 3):

@heneryville,
I don't have the exact info u are looking for but what we do is we use match whenever we need preety or custom url's, for others the default actions that are provided by resources statement are just enough.